# merge sort program in c++ not working

Tags: c++, algorithm, runtime-error, c++14, mergesort

I have written this program in c++ to implement the merge sort algorithm, but it seems to be giving a run-time error. The moment I enter the data of the array elements it stops responding. Now, I don't know what else to write, as stack overflow can't accept a question mostly code, so here is my code. Please someone tell me what is causing the error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void merge(int arr[], int left, int mid, int right) 
{
    int i, j, count = left, l[mid-left +1], r[right-mid];
    for(i = 0; i <= mid-left; i++)
    {
        l[i] = arr[left + i];
    }
    for(j = 0; j <= right-mid-1; j++)
    {
        r[j] = arr[j + mid + 1];
    }

    i = j = 0;
    while(i <= mid-left && j <= right-mid-1)
    {
        if(l[i] <= r[j])
        {
            arr[count] = l[i];
            i++;
        }
        else if(r[j] < l[i])
        {
            arr[count] = r[j];
            j++;
        }
        count++;
    }
   while(i <= mid-left)
   {
        arr[count] = l[i];
        i++;count++;
   }
   while(j <= right-mid-1)
   {
        arr[count] = r[j];
        j++;count++;
   }
}
void mergesort(int arr[], int left, int right)
{
    if(left > right) return;
    int mid = (left + right)/2;

    mergesort(arr, left, mid);
    mergesort(arr, mid+1, right);

    merge(arr, left, mid, right);
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout<<"No. of elements : ";
    cin>>n;
    int arr[n] ;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    mergesort(arr,0,n-1);
    cout<<"sorted array : \n";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit : Everyone i am using c++14 (GCC compiler) and variable sized array is not a problem in my compiler .I ave used it many times .The main thing i am asking is ,is there any problem in my algorithm usage.

Comment: Variable length arrays aren't allowed in C++, the number of elements in an array must be a compile-known constant, so int i, j, count = left, l[mid - left + 1], r[right - mid]; won't compile, or shouldn't.

Comment: Neither will `int arr[n]` compile, as that is also not valid C++ syntax.  Use `std::vector<int>` instead.

Comment: @Zebrafish GCC extension allows the use VLAs in C++.

Comment: @Yashas dopesn't mean you should use it, though. VLA has a quite a few downsides. For example, enter an `n` of a million and watch the weird errors as the stack overflows and `sizeof` is no longer a compile time constant.

Comment: Hello,everyone,the code still doesnt work for vector usage. but the main thing is , i think you guys are talking about the old c++ compilers,like turbo c++ .I used borland and GCC compiler ,and i have created variable sized array a lot of times.

Comment: @agnivabasak You are correct that your error does not stem from VLA use. The program will have problems if the user inputs a fairly large `n`, but that will be a different issue. You are incorrect about the validity of VLA, though. No C++ Standard revisions all the way back to the original 1998 Standard have allowed Variable Length Arrays. Some compiler implementations have allowed it as an extension, probably for improved compatibility with C. It should be noted that VLA are now considered optional in C, so you can't really count on them being present in C either.

Comment: Are you deliberately re-writing `std::inplace_merge`?

Comment: @agnivabasak -- Also if you had an out-of-bounds error, there is no way to detect it using VLA's.  At least with `std::vector`, you have a chance of detecting such errors using `std::vector::at()`.  Many questions on StackOverflow that uses VLA's have been easily solved by changing to vector and calling `at()` instead of `[ ]`.

Comment: @Caleth I was just trying out merge sort in c++ as it's a really helpful algo used in competitive programming in which i am engaged right now :) .

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie and user4581301 Thanks for the info ,i will keep it in mind , next time i use VLA

Comment: Yes, and your `merge` is trying to do the same thing as `std::inplace_merge`. You don't need to rewrite it

Comment: Have a look on  below source-code,where you would find  a better approach        https://straightcoder234fgps.blogspot.com/2018/10/merge-sort-source-code-using-vector.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem was the condition you used for termination of merge sort. When you use `if (left > right)` and `left` and `right` are same, then `mid` is same as `left`. So the recursion never stops. Use the following condition.

```
void mergesort(int arr[],int left,int right)
{
    if(left >= right) return ;
```

Comment: Thankyou ,very much .The algorithm is totally clear to me now.